# How to properly ask for extension on assessment projects

Tags: software-industry, time-management, burnout

I have been trying really frantically to apply for a software engineering internship for my university graduation requirements, which I have never secured one before, and for most jobs that reached out to me after receiving my resume, I either screwed up the technical interview or it never happened, because there are unstable scenarios happening in all companies everyday due to the Coronavirus and interviews get postponed.

4 Weeks ago, a company gave me a technical project that seemed doable for someone with the right experience, which is quite different from the 1.5h technical interview. It involves answering 2 programming challenges, while writing my time taken for each of the tasks, and also a mini-project to write a backend RESTFUL API. I took modules in school that covered the foundation for the project, but never applied the skills on a real project, which involved deployment, schema design and learning new programming languages and softwares on the fly.

The good thing is, for all these 3 assessments, the company allowed me to set a deadline as they are taking in interns on a rolling basis, and also ask for an extension where necessary. Despite the tight timeline I need for the project, I also need to juggle with school work as my exams are nearing, and I promised the company to submit it today, which is a Sunday.

The company has told me in the email that when all their hiring positions have been filled up, they will inform everyone who did not manage to finish the interview process. In the 4 weeks, I spent 3 weeks juggling school commitments and finding other internship opportunities, which of course was not too successful. Since they have not sent me a follow up, I assume that they’re still hiring in this difficult situation.

I only started working on the 3 assessments since 1 week ago, and manage to complete the first 2 programming challenges. However, for the mini-project, I have been facing a lot of difficulties meeting the technical requirements and also meeting the deadline, which is today. I learnt everything as a beginner on the fly, and I think I’ve made 70% of it functional, if I had to give an estimate. However, I only achieved this much progress on the Saturday.

I panicked to ask for an extension on that Saturday, and screwed up sending 2 emails, because I left out the new deadline, 1 week extra from the current one, from the first email.

It is expected that the recruiting officer may not get back to me on time regarding the extension as it is a weekend, and I’m having a dilemma deciding over 2 alternatives:

1) Submit what I have now, tell them the reason why I am not able to complete it due to the deadline(and pretend that an extension was never requested or approved)

2) Assume the extension has been approved, and just try my best to submit all the technical requirements by the suggested deadline.

I am quite desperate for this internship as I have tried really hard to reach out for more opportunities, which has been made even more difficult due to the Coronavirus situation, and also my skills hardly meet any of the requirements stated on the jobs.

Also, I actually am at greater risk of asking for another extension beyond the first one as I have not been studying for my exams, but the deadlines at which the university decide to accept conversion of self-sourced internships into credits forced me into giving another deadline.

I want to know what’s the best alternative I can take right now to ensure my maximum chance of qualifying as an intern.

Comment: So, if I follow this long post, you have already sent two requests for an extension and now wantvto send a third? IMHO you won’t be on their list much longer.

Comment: No, I've only sent out 1 request for extension, which I did with 2 emails, the 2nd may happen after somewhere in the week, but it's unlikely because I cannot commit more than 1 week of extra time. My dilemma is not knowing whether to submit my current work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for an extension, be consistent and assume it will be granted, until you hear otherwise. I wouldn't be impressed by an applicant who didn't finish the project. In the real world, while missing deadlines can have severe consequences, it's much better to produce something to be proud of.